# Why this MySQL query wont work

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select p_product 
from (select p_product, count(p_product) 
      from rental 
      group by p_product 
      order by count(p_product) desc LIMIT 5);
```

> Error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: You need to give your sub-query an alias.

Comment: All you had to do was put the error message into SO's search field to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add an alias to the subquery:

```
select p_product
from (
    select p_product,
        count(p_product)
    from rental
    group by p_product
    order by count(p_product) desc LIMIT 5
    ) t;
------^ here
```

Also, you dont really need a subquery:

```
select p_product
from rental
group by p_product
order by count(p_product) desc LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Exactly, I dont need a subquery for this. I was just checking how it works with an example.

Thanks.